# Show complete row where one column is duplicate

Tags: sql, duplicates

I can't seem to know how to find something on this.
Here is my example which shows me just the duplicate column:

```
select column1,COUNT(column1)
    from table
    where column1> 0
    GROUP BY column1
    HAVING COUNT(column1) > 1
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
----------------------------
column1 | (name not defined)
----------------------------
2134567 | 2
2881992 | 3
```

**What I want is:**

```
------------------------------------------------
column0 | column2 |column1 | (name not defined)
------------------------------------------------
1       |     abc |2134567 | 2
2       |     cde |2881992 | 3
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you add a complete example, including the contents of the table you're querying?

Comment: Do you dynamically need strings abc and cde?

Comment: Matt gave me answer I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join your query back to the table you want to pull in the additional data from

```
SELECT column0, column2, table.column1, columncount
FROM table 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT column1, COUNT(column1) columncount
                FROM table
                WHERE column1> 0
                GROUP BY column1 HAVING COUNT(column1) > 1) t2 ON table.column1 = t2.column1
```

Comment: As soon as I can accept your answer I will ;) Thanks alot, not very good in SQL

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM [Tanle1]
WHERE Column0 IN
     (SELECT Column0 FROM [Table1]
      GROUP BY Column0
      HAVING COUNT(Column0) > 1)
```